# Using different lines to plot different datasets in gnu plot

Tags: gnuplot

When I run the following gnuplot code, I get the error message
"duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options" at plot.

```
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

set key right outside

set terminal png enhanced size 1500,1000 font "Arial,20"

set output graphDataDir."graph.eps"

plot [0.5:] for [fname1 in list1] graphDataDir.fname1 using 1:2 with l title fname1 linewidth 2, \
for [fname2 in list2] graphDataDir.fname2 using 1:2 with lines dt 4 title fname2 linewidth 2;
```

What I'd like to do is using solid lines for the datas in "list1", and dashed lines for "list2".

"list1", "list2" contains the list of file names and "graphDataDir" is the directory path to the files, which are given in the command line argument.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is uncomplete code. Where are `graphDataDir`, `list1` and `list2` defined? Furthermore, check the syntax of `sprintf` via `help sprintf`, although, just for concatenating strings, `graphDataDir.fname1` would be enough. Please revise your code and in case there are still problems edit the question with a minimal but complete  (non-)working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is because in the second clause of your plot command the list of line properties `dt 4 ... lw 2` is interrupted by something else `title foo`, so the program treats it as two *different* sets of line properties and complains that you can only have one set.  The fix is to change

```
using 1:2 with lines dt 4 title fname2 linewidth 2
```

to

```
using 1:2 with lines dt 4 linewidth 2 title fname2
```

It doesn't matter what in order the line properties (color, width, dash type, etc) are given but all the properties must be together.

Comment: Thank you so much :)  I also forgot to change "set terminal png" to "set terminal postscript eps".